# lua redis handle errors

Tags: linux, lua, redis

I use lua-script to set keys to redis:

```
local redis = require("redis")
local connected, client = pcall(redis.connect, '127.0.0.1', 6379)
client:set(key, value)
```

Sometimes, when I execute: **client:set(key, value)**, I got error: *Connection time out* and application crashes.

How can I handle this error issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
local status, result = pcall(function() client:set(key, value) end)
```